# Lines on Donut after texture painting

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, shaders

[image][image: There are these weird lines of 'N's on my donut]

[image]

I've been following the BlenderGuru's tutorial, I'm at the last part of level 2. unfortunately I found this weird line (looks like'N's) on the inside of my donut. I've just finished doing texturing using nodes. I've no idea where it came from.

One major deviation from the tutorial I did is applying a decimate modifier to lessen my vertices (subdivide subsurface modifier too much).

The Second picture showcases the problem using viewport shading.

EDIT: Included the UV map of the donut. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi :) there ,can you attach an image of the unwrapped model of the donut .Thanks

Comment: Sorry took a while had to relearn unwrapping :/ I've edited the post to include the UV map of the donut, hope it helps

Comment: How did you unwrap? DIdn't change the UVs at all? Decimate modifier will mess up existing UVs, unless you restrict it to seams, default unwrap does not have seams. Why would you subdivide and then use decimate anyways, can't you just not subdive as heavily?

Comment: I can't say for sure.Decimate modifier does something like triangulating the faces . It might be the problem Though that line kinda looks cool in it.I can't understand your UV

Comment: My bad guys, I just used the UV-unwrap and went to the UV editor. Also yes I shouldn't have subdivided as much lol, but I had only one save of the whole project (pea brain move yes) and I thought I had too many vertices. You guys were right tho, it was the decimate modifier that gave the weird lines on the donut. I manage to get rid of it now though by decimating the donut again and then re-applying a subdivide modifier. I'll be sure to make a better, helpful post next time I'd ask a question haha. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get rid of the lines by decimating the donut again until the I got a more basic mesh of the donut and then re-applying the subdivide modifier.

[image: DonutNoLines]
[image: DonutUVNoLines]